# Is it possible to select base station to connect to?

Tags: mobile-network

There are applications that show the base stations around, but is there a way to select the base station to connect, inside the phone provider of course?

For example, if my provider XYZ has 3 base stations around my current place, how can I select one to connect to? How to change?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It's not the phone that decides on the base station to pick. The stations decide when and who to hand over the connection.